# Do we really need $X$ to be compact Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, ring-theory

Let $R= C(X,\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of all continuous real-valued functions on a topological space $X$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the standard Euclidean topology. Suppose $|X|>1$ and $X$ is connected and compact Hausdorff. Then the only idempotents in $R$ are the functions $0$ and $1$. Prove also that if $R$ is Von Neumann regular then $R$ is a field.

Proof:

We clearly have that $0^2=0$ and $1^2=1$. Now take $f \in R$ such that $f$ is idempotent. Then, for all $x \in X$, we have that $f^2(x)-f(x)=0$. This equation has only two solutions in $\mathbb{R}$, namely $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$. Now define
\begin{align*}
A:=\lbrace x \in X \mid f(x)=0 \rbrace=f^{-1}(\lbrace 0 \rbrace) \\
B:= \lbrace x \in X \mid f(x)=1 \rbrace=f^{-1}(\lbrace 1 \rbrace)\end{align*}
Since $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the standard Euclidean topology, we know that all the singletons are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. The continuity of $f$ implies that $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $X$. Furthermore, we have that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cup B =X$. Assume that both $A$ and $B$ are non-empty (which is possible since $|X|>1$), then connectedness of $X$ gives us a contradiction. So we must have that $A=X$ and $B= \emptyset$ (and thus $f=0$), or $A= \emptyset$ and $B=X$ (and thus $f=1$).

Assume that $R$ is Von Neumann regular. Then, for every non-zero $f \in R$, we have that $(f)=(e)$, where $e \in R$ is idempotent. It follows that $(f)=R$ and thus $f$ is invertible. Hence, $R$ is a field.

Now, my question is the following: why did we need $X$ to be compact Hausdorff?

Comment: My bad, I'm not familiar with the reputation system on Stackexchange so I thought it was possible to accept both answers. Apparently not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right that the assumption $X$ is Hausdorff is unnecessary... all that matters is that the topology *on $\mathbb R$* is enough to make points closed.

As for compactness, I think you are also right that it is unnecessary.  Connectedness, the fact that $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology is $T_2$ (or even just $T_1$) and the continuity of the maps is all that's necessary to conclude there are only trivial idempotents.

And a VNR ring with trivial idempotents is a division ring, for exactly the reasons you gave.

---

Added:

Here's a screenshot of the solution from the companion book *Exercises in classical ring theory*

[image]

As you can see, the additional hypothesis that $X$ be compact and Hausdorff was used in the proof **to appeal to the classification of maximal ideals of $C(X,\mathbb R)$**.  The theorem in question says that the maximal ideals are exactly of the form $M_c=\{f\mid f(c)=0\}$.

It looks like in this case, the author simply did not notice the elementary proof you have given above (that Hausdorff+connected+VNR implies field.)

Not sure exactly what the precise wording of the edition you're looking at is, but my guess is that it is aimed at using this same path to a solution.

Comment: No, not really. It was an exercise from the book 'A first course in non-commutative ring theory' by T.Y. Lam.

Comment: @J.Bosser Is it part of a family of exercises? It really does seem to be this elementary to prove this particular part of the statement.

Comment: No, the exercise was independent from the other exercises

Comment: @J.Bosser Can you tell me the section/problem number actually?

Comment: Chapter 4 on the Jacobson Radical, exercise 13.

Comment: @J.Bosser Are you sure you're not mixing two problems? When i look up exercise 4.13 in "Exercises in Classical Ring theory" (the solution manual for that book) it says "Let $R=C(X,\mathbb R)$ and show that $R$ is jacobson semisimple, but usually not von Neumann regular."

Comment: The exercise that we were given is an adjustment of this exercise. We first had to prove that $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ is $J$-semisimple.

Comment: @J.Bosser I've made some educated guesses and modified my answer. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Secondly, we had to prove that statement that I gave.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. We did not need to proof the last part involving the classification theorem.

Comment: @J.Bosser Yes... it seems to be overkill when you already have that "every nonzero principal ideal generates the entire ring."

Comment: @J.Bosser The solution above even mentions "a contradiction" but it's not clear at all when it was assumed $|X|>1$.  So perhaps this is a result of incomplete solution rewrites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So just to be clear once and for all: for my solution it is enough to assume that $X$ is connected?

Comment: @J.Bosser As far as I can see! The compactness looks like a kludge left over from an earlier explanation of the proof.  Inverse image of closed sets are closed, the inverse images of $0,1$ forms a disconnection of $X$ --> only trivial idempotents. I can't see anywhere where this breaks down... it seems that simple.  Maybe the point is to drive home the connection to $|X|$.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a standard topological fact that $X$ connected implies that $C(X)$ only has two-idempotents, and you've basically given the standard proof for it. It's part of exercise 1B in Gilman and Jerrison's classic "Rings of continuous functions". Compactness nor Hausdorffness are needed. Nor is $|X|>1$ needed: if $X$ is a singleton, then $C(X) \simeq \mathbb{R}$ and it's also true. Only connectedness matters.